# Kendo ui scheduler - change date format

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, date-format, kendo-scheduler

I'm able to change the format of the dates for a kendo ui scheduler on the column headers using the dateHeaderTemplate property but I need to change the format of the date highlighted in the image below: [image: Kendo UI Scheduler]

I'm sure there must be a pretty simple way of doing this but haven't found anything in the telerik docs so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
    views: [
   "day",
   { type: "week", selected: true },
   "month",
   "agenda",
   "timeline"
    ],
    dataBound: scheduler_dataBound,
    dataSource: [
      {
          id: 1,
          start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
          end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
          title: "Interview"
      }
    ]
});
function scheduler_dataBound(e) {
    if (this.viewName() != "month") {
        var test = $(".k-lg-date-format").html().split('-'); 
        var _str = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(test[0].trim()), 'ddd MM/dd');
        if (test.length == 2) {
            _str += " - " + kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(test[1].trim()), 'ddd MM/dd');
        } 
        $(".k-lg-date-format").html(_str);
        $(".k-sm-date-format").html(_str); 
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jayesh but this appears to be just changing the format of the day column headers, which I am already able to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jayesh, the solution was almost perfect for me just that I was not able to use .html().split(), I had to reference the model property like _model.formattedDate.split()