# Kendo UI Scheduler - Changing date format, ASP.NET MVC version

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I have the same problem like this: [change date format, using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773490/kendo-ui-scheduler-change-date-format)

but I'm using the ASP.NET MVC version. There is no 'Databound' element for 'Html.Kendo().Scheduler<...>()'.

So where can I put that 'scheduler_dataBound' function? Or is there another different solution from the javascript version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a data binding event on the MVC wrapper one:
You can also do  `e.Navigate("scheduler_navigate");` and  `e.DataBound("scheduler_dataBound");`

```
 .Events(e =>
                    {                      
                        e.DataBinding("scheduler_dataBinding");                      
                    })



<script>

function scheduler_dataBound(e) {
    if (this.viewName() != "month") {
        var test = $(".k-lg-date-format").html().split('-'); 
        var _str = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(test[0].trim()), 'ddd MM/dd');
        if (test.length == 2) {
            _str += " - " + kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(test[1].trim()), 'ddd MM/dd');
        } 
        $(".k-lg-date-format").html(_str);
        $(".k-sm-date-format").html(_str); 
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's a link to the rest of the events
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/scheduler/events

Comment: I've added some lines in function code 'cause when I clicked to create an event, or changed the date selecting from the calendar, it returned "null - null" instead of the days of the week selected. Anyway I didn't know databound is in the events, thank you!